# Dart's built_value library, how to generate the serializer file in flutter?

Tags: serialization, dart, flutter

- I've added the built_value dependency.
- I've created a file `serializers.dart` with the serializer field.
- I've converted one of my data classes to the required format.

How do I actually build the project to generate the `serializers.g.dart` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In recent versions you need a `@SerializersFor()` annotation

See also the example project https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/chat_example/lib/data_model/serializers.dart

```
library serializers;

import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:chat_example/data_model/data_model.dart';

part 'serializers.g.dart';

/// Collection of generated serializers for the built_value chat example.
@SerializersFor(const [
  Chat,
  ListUsers,
  ListUsersResponse,
  Login,
  LoginResponse,
  ShowChat,
  Status,
  Welcome,
])
final Serializers serializers = _$serializers;
```

Comment: And remember you need to run your build.dart/watch.dart by hand--it's not part of the flutter build process. e.g. run `dart tool/build.dart`. See the example projects for an example build.dart/watch.dart.

Comment: @DavidMorgan yes that's what I was missing