# failed due to: Bad state: No builder factory for BuiltList

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using `builtvalue` for my `PODO` class

Following is my json response

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "msg": "Success",
    "allotmentMasterID": "1",
    "allotmentInfoID": "1",
    "category": [
        {
            "categoryID": "1",
            "categoryName": "Major",
            "selectedCount": "0",
            "status": 1
        },
        {
            "categoryID": "2",
            "categoryName": "Mandatory",
            "selectedCount": "0",
            "status": 0
        },
        {
            "categoryID": "3",
            "categoryName": "Minor",
            "selectedCount": "0",
            "status": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created a `built value` for this

Following are the classes

```
library specialisation_model_first_screen;

import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';
import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';

part 'specialisation_model_first_screen.g.dart';

abstract class SpecialisationModelFirstScreen
    implements
        Built<SpecialisationModelFirstScreen,
            SpecialisationModelFirstScreenBuilder> {
  SpecialisationModelFirstScreen._();

  factory SpecialisationModelFirstScreen(
          [updates(SpecialisationModelFirstScreenBuilder b)]) =
      _$SpecialisationModelFirstScreen;

  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'status')
  int get status;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'msg')
  String get msg;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'allotmentMasterID')
  String get allotmentMasterID;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'allotmentInfoID')
  String get allotmentInfoID;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'category')
  BuiltList<Category> get category;

  static Serializer<SpecialisationModelFirstScreen> get serializer =>
      _$specialisationModelFirstScreenSerializer;
}

abstract class Category implements Built<Category, CategoryBuilder> {
  Category._();

  factory Category([updates(CategoryBuilder b)]) = _$Category;

  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'categoryID')
  String get categoryID;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'categoryName')
  String get categoryName;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'selectedCount')
  String get selectedCount;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'status')
  int get status;

  static Serializer<Category> get serializer => _$categorySerializer;
}



library serializers;

import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';

part 'package:dice_clutter/models/serializers/serializers.g.dart';

@SerializersFor(const [SpecialisationModelFirstScreen])

Serializers serializers = _$serializers;

Serializers standardSerializers = (serializers.toBuilder()..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())).build();
```

Following is my `serializers.g.dart` file

```
part of serializers;
Serializers _$serializers = (new Serializers().toBuilder()
      ..add(SpecialisationModelFirstScreen.serializer))
    .build();
```

When i am making an `api` request i am getting the response correctly but following error is thrown

`failed due to: Bad state: No builder factory for BuiltList<Category>.` `Fix by adding one, see SerializersBuilder.addBuilderFactory.`

Is this a bug in `build value` library itself or am i doing something wrong?

In some cases - and I do not fully understand specific reasons - my objects fail to deserialize with StandartJsonPlugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to edit my serializers.g.dart file as follows

```
Serializers _$serializers = (new Serializers().toBuilder()
  ..add(SpecialisationModelFirstScreen.serializer)
   ..add(Category.serializer)
  ..addBuilderFactory(
      const FullType(
          BuiltList, const [const FullType(Category)]),
          () => new ListBuilder<Category>())
)
    .build();
```

Thanks to `Tensor Programming` Video on `Youtube`
There is some bug in the builtvalue library as it is not able to generate `serializers.g.dart` properly in some cases. Hope It gets resolved in the future

Comment: You don't and should not edit the generated files. See the answer from @jordan-davies there correct way to fix this issue is you need to add your class to `@SerializersFor` annotation, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47826184/85472

Comment: I should also add that if you do need to call `..addBuilfFactory()` like you do for a built list you need to do it inside your own code where you have your serializers, for example see built_values own tests:  https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/built_value/test/standard_json_plugin_test.dart#L13

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `Category` class to the list of classes that can be serialized:

```
@SerializersFor(const [
  SpecialisationModelFirstScreen,
  Category, <-- Category available for serialization
])
```

then regenerate your `built_value` classes.

More details can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47826184/85472)

Comment: did you regenerate your classes after making this change?

Answer (score 0):

base on [JSON and serialization - Flutter](https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes) and your code ,

you are missing fromJson ,

using  [JSON to Dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

see the fromJson function

```
class Autogenerated {
  int status;
  String msg;
  String allotmentMasterID;
  String allotmentInfoID;
  List<Category> category;

  Autogenerated(
      {this.status,
      this.msg,
      this.allotmentMasterID,
      this.allotmentInfoID,
      this.category});

  Autogenerated.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    msg = json['msg'];
    allotmentMasterID = json['allotmentMasterID'];
    allotmentInfoID = json['allotmentInfoID'];
    if (json['category'] != null) {
      category = new List<Category>();
      json['category'].forEach((v) {
        category.add(new Category.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['msg'] = this.msg;
    data['allotmentMasterID'] = this.allotmentMasterID;
    data['allotmentInfoID'] = this.allotmentInfoID;
    if (this.category != null) {
      data['category'] = this.category.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Category {
  String categoryID;
  String categoryName;
  String selectedCount;
  int status;

  Category(
      {this.categoryID, this.categoryName, this.selectedCount, this.status});

  Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    categoryID = json['categoryID'];
    categoryName = json['categoryName'];
    selectedCount = json['selectedCount'];
    status = json['status'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['categoryID'] = this.categoryID;
    data['categoryName'] = this.categoryName;
    data['selectedCount'] = this.selectedCount;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: That part i guess is optional as i have not written for my other Api Response and they work fine for me. Even in the boring show  they have not included the json part

Comment: @Nudge yes , not sure ‍♂️  if it's required ,but  BuiltList<Category> is a complex object not like as string or a number , i use formJson usually ,